# How to align button to right side of the navigation Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Need to add a new button to the right side of the navigation bar.

[image]

```
<ion-header>
```

```
<button ion-button menuToggle side="left">
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>

<button ion-button side="right">
  <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
</button>

<ion-title>Notification</ion-title></ion-navbar></ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons right>
    <button ion-button icon-only><ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```